# Multithreading with urlib2

Tags: python, multithreading

Im trying to speed up my program when querying an api using urilib2. To do this Ive tried to write in multithreading.

However when I run the code it errors with the following and I get no response via the urlib2 calls.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
  File "./myscript", line 333, in query_api
  File "./myscript", line 350, in issue_request
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1198, in https_open
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1164, in do_open
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
Exception in thread Thread-2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
  File "./myscript", line 333, in query_api
  File "./myscript", line 350, in issue_request
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1198, in https_open
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1164, in do_open
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
```

My code is :

```
class ApiMultiThreadHelper:

    def __init__(self,api_calls):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.api_datastore = {}
        self.api_calls = api_calls
        self.userpass = '#####'

    def query_api(self,q,api_query):
        self.q.put(self.issue_request(api_query))

    def issue_request(self,api_query):

        self.api_datastore.update({api_query:{}})

        for lookup in ["call1","call2"]:
            query = api_query+lookup

            request = urllib2.Request(query)
            request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % self.userpass)
            f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            response = f.read()
            f.close()

            self.api_datastore[api_query].update({lookup:response})

        return True

    def go(self):
        for i in self.api_calls:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.query_api, args = (self.q,i))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

        return self.api_datastore
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib2` should be thread-safe. It's a guess, but...

> Exception in thread Thread-2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)

This suggests that you are not waiting for your threads to finish the job. The problematic line is this one:

```
t.daemon = True
```

The consequence is that when the main thread exits everything is killed (the main thread will wait only for non-daemons). Try removing that line. Also you should do a proper joining:

```
threads = []
for i in self.api_calls:
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.query_api, args = (self.q,i))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()  # <--- wait for all threads to finish their jobs
```

Comment: Spot on, worked like a charm..... theres another question around the same kind of thing i just posted if you fancy a ganders --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682154/limiting-threads-within-python-threading-queue