# Limiting Threads within Python Threading, Queue

Tags: python

Im using the following code to multithread urlib2. However what is the best way to limit the number of threads that it consumes ??

```
class ApiMultiThreadHelper:

    def __init__(self,api_calls):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.api_datastore = {}
        self.api_calls = api_calls
        self.userpass = '#####'

    def query_api(self,q,api_query):
        self.q.put(self.issue_request(api_query))

    def issue_request(self,api_query):

        self.api_datastore.update({api_query:{}})

        for lookup in ["call1","call2"]:
            query = api_query+lookup

            request = urllib2.Request(query)
            request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % self.userpass)
            f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            response = f.read()
            f.close()

            self.api_datastore[api_query].update({lookup:response})

        return True

    def go(self):
        threads = []
        for i in self.api_calls:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.query_api, args = (self.q,i))
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)

        for t in threads:
            t.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a thread pool. Here's my implementation I've made years ago (Python 3.x friendly):

```
import traceback
from threading import Thread
try:
    import queue as Queue  # Python3.x
except ImportError:
    import Queue

class ThreadPool(object):
    def __init__(self, no=10):
        self.alive = True
        self.tasks = Queue.Queue()
        self.threads = []
        for _ in range(no):
            t = Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.start()
            self.threads.append(t)

    def worker(self):
        while self.alive:
            try:
                fn, args, kwargs = self.tasks.get(timeout=0.5)
            except Queue.Empty:
                continue
            except ValueError:
                self.tasks.task_done()
                continue

            try:
                fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception:
                # might wanna add some better error handling
                traceback.print_exc()

            self.tasks.task_done()

    def add_job(self, fn, args=[], kwargs={}):
        self.tasks.put((fn, args, kwargs))

    def join(self):
        self.tasks.join()

    def deactivate(self):
        self.alive = False
        for t in self.threads:
            t.join()
```

You can also find a similar class in `multiprocessing.pool` module (don't ask me why it is there). You can then refactor your code like this:

```
def go(self):
    tp = ThreadPool(20)  # <-- 20 thread workers
    for i in self.api_calls:
        tp.add_job(self.query_api, args=(self.q, i))
    tp.join()
    tp.deactivate()
```

Number of threads is now defined a priori.